# chrome dev tools network request name

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know of a way to display the full network resource request url instead of just the last part of it in chrome dev tools plz?

Right now it's showing me only the last part of the resource url: `1` or `2` for requests to `/users/1` and `/users/2`. Since I have multiple resource urls ending in `/:id`, this get confusing very fast.

When I hover the name I get a title with the full request url. It would be nice to be able to see it without needing to hover over each separate request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a button in view:

[image]

which enables larger request rows.
so you get this:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems View button is moved since latest version of Chrome
[image]